# Building a vagrant box with apache2 pre installed

Tags: vagrant, packer

Hello I am new to vagrant and packer and I am trying to build a vagrant box with apache2 pre installed. Everytime I build the box add it then ssh into it apache is not installed. my script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash 
set -e
set -v


# http://superuser.com/questions/196848/how-do-i-create-an-administrator-user-on-ubuntu
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/redirecting-stdout-to-a-file-you-dont-have-write-permission-on
# This line assumes the user you created in the preseed directory is vagrant
echo "vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" | sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/init-users
sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/init-users


# Installing vagrant keys
wget --no-check-certificate 'https://raw.github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/master/keys/vagrant.pub'
sudo mkdir -p /home/vagrant/.ssh
sudo chown -R vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.ssh
cat ./vagrant.pub >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/authorized_keys

apt-get install -y apache2
# Change apache to run as vagrant:vagrant
# https://github.com/ChiperSoft/Packer-Vagrant-Example/blob/master/packer/scripts/packages.sh
sed -i s/www-data/vagrant/ /etc/apache2/envvars


echo "All Done!"
```

Am I doing this right?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the script you proide above, but the error is most likely in you workflow/understanding of Packer and Vagrant. If you provide the commands you run I can problably help you with what's wrong.

Comment: These are the commands I did:

Comment: These are the commands I did: pakcer build ubuntu.json, then i go to the directory of the build, vagrant init, I then edit the vagrantfile to read       config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080,, vagrant add box ubuntu.json --name test, after I ssh into the machine apache is not there

Comment: its not clear why you have `ubuntu/xenial64` as the box defined in your Vagrantfile, you should use the test box you just added/created from packer

Comment: if there's nothing particular in your box except the installation of apache, it might be better to work with a box from altas (such as `ubuntu/xenial64`) and run a provisioning to install apache

Answer (score 0):

When you have built your vagrant box with Packer you need to add it with `vagrant box add <name> <packer-box-file>` after that you can do `vagrant init <name> && vagrant up`.